# Run same class 5 times

Tags: java

I've wrote a complicated algorithm in java code. However, I want to run the code class 5 times without doing it my self. I called T1 class by T2 class and put T1 class in loop for 5 times. The problem is Java save the old values for the code and use them in the next loop. My question is how to run T1 class for 5 times every time each time with new values (without using zero for static variables) at the end of T1 code. Here is a simple example for what I've done:
    package Test;

```
public class T1 {
    public static int n, m, o, i, j;
    public static double T;
    public static int[][]  V = new int[100][100];
    public static int[]  C = new int [100];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        m=o+1; n=o+1; o=m+n;
        for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
            for(i = 0 ; i < m ; i++){
                V[i][j] = i+j+o;
                System.out.print(V[i][j]+"   ");
            }           
                System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("--------");
        for(j = 0 ; j < n ; j++){
            C[j] = j+o;
            System.out.print(C[j]+"   ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n--------");
        System.out.println("o = "+o);
        System.out.println("*******************************");
    }
}
```

---

```
package Test;

public class T2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i =0 ; i <5 ; i++){
            T1.main(args);
        }
    }
}
```

the result for these codes are:

```
2   
--------
2   
--------
o = 2
*******************************
6   7   8   
7   8   9   
8   9   10   
--------
6   7   8   
--------
o = 6
*******************************
14   15   16   17   18   19   20   
15   16   17   18   19   20   21   
16   17   18   19   20   21   22   
17   18   19   20   21   22   23   
18   19   20   21   22   23   24   
19   20   21   22   23   24   25   
20   21   22   23   24   25   26   
--------
14   15   16   17   18   19   20   
--------
o = 14
*******************************
```

while I want them to be as following (without put o=0 at the end of T1 class):

```
2   
--------
2   
--------
o = 2
*******************************
2   
--------
2   
--------
o = 2
*******************************
2   
--------
2   
--------
o = 2
*******************************
```

Comment: `static` is what you want to change and create `T1` objects instead of calling the static `T1.main` method

Comment: Move the algorithm into another method of the original class and then use the main method to call that function 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

You have everything defined in `T1` as `static` which means that the variables are bound to the class and not to instances of the class. You need to remove all `static` specifiers from fields and methods and create a new instance in each loop iteration. Also do not put your code in `main`, instead in an other method wich is not staitc.

```
for(int i =0 ; i <5 ; i++){
    new T1().process(args);
}
```

If you need to keep all variables static you could introduce a `static reset()` method where you set all variable to their default values (the values they had before the first call) and call that method after each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for helping, the problem is when I remove static the code gives error in running, it should stay static. For this I ask.

Comment: @John Please update your question with your changed code along with the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

Because of using static keyword, at every iteration you change the values of your attributes. Remove static and it should be fine, that if you cannot make separate method in T1 class and just call it in T2 for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities to **reset the static values**:

The first and easier one would be to save your old state, e. g.

```
for(int i =0 ; i <5 ; i++){
    final int n = T1.n;

    T1.main(args);

    T1.n = n;
}
```

Another option would be to load your class T with a different Class Loader each time, as for the JVM would hold one *Class* instance for each loader, and they all would have their own static fields.

```
Class<?> instance1 = /* some magic using classloaders */;
Method instance1 = c.getMethod("method", new Class[]{String[].class});
Object result = m.invoke(null, /*your args come here*/);
```

But I don't think thats what you want here.

---

Why dont you just **make all the fields non-static**, and then create new instances?

```
class T1 {
    private int n;

    T1() {
        n = 5;
    }

    void doSomething() {
        //do whatever you want with your variables here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=1; i<5; i++) {
             T1 t1 = new T1();
             t1.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome - have you considered one of my first suggestions, either save all values manually or load class instances dynamically? Both would allow your fields to stay static.